# PyQt5 QTreeView auto collapses on checking a child node

Tags: python, pyqt, treeview, pyqt5, qtreeview

I have a `QTreeView` in PyQt5 with checkable parent and child nodes. I can expand the parent node and have callbacks to select/deselect all child nodes on selecting/deselecting the parent node. This behavior works fine.

But when I deselect or select any of the child nodes, the whole tree collapses by default (figure on the right). Ideally, I'd like the tree to maintain the state it is in, whenever a child node is selected or deselected. Is there a flag for `QTreeView` to override and not have this default behavior of collapsing all the child nodes?

**My attempt so far:**
I keep track of the `QModelIndex` of the parent item whenever a child node is clicked and then call the `expand` function on the `QTreeView` object with this parent item's `QModelIndex` as the argument. But this doesn't seem to prevent the behavior mentioned above. However, the `expandAll` function seems to work fine. But this has the downside of expanding the children of other parents which are not of interest. I'd rather keep them collapsed if that was their state.

Does anyone have any inputs?

[image]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631822/tracking-checked-items-in-qtreewidget-when-loading-in-new-set-of-data

Comment: In a QTreeView with a QStandardItemModel I don't see that problem, if you want help provide a [MRE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to use the model's index instead of the item's index to keep track of the expanded states of all the parent nodes.

`model.index(item.index().row(), 0)`

instead of

`item.index()`